# List the supported volume types for ebs devices on aws using sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to list the supported volume types for ebs devices on aws using java sdk. After searching on internet I found an enum([volumeType](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticsearch/model/VolumeType.html#values--)) for that. But that enum does not list sc1 and st1 type of volumes. So is there is any api to list the existing volume types supported by aws?

Answer (score 1):

Your link takes you to the ElasticSearch class, [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/VolumeType.html) this links to the EC2 Class that does list them all.

```
Enum Constants
Enum Constant and Description
Gp2 
Io1 
Sc1 
St1 
Standard
```

If you are using the Java SDK to create an ElasticSearch cluster it looks like from the API that it does not support sc1 and st1 yet.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html#es-createdomain-configure-ebs

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-configuration-api.html#es-configuration-api-datatypes-ebsoptions

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.

Comment: Apart from the Enum is there any API available to get the list. If any new type is added later then it can be listed without upgrading the sdk.